# How could the two threads enter the synchronized block at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

There is some weird thing happening. As I enter the synchronized block,I try to print the name of the Thread.After the print statement,I make a husge pause of 100000 seconds.

```
@Override
public int getNextAvailableVm() {
    synchronized(this) {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        try {Thread.sleep(100000000);}catch(Exception exc){}

        String dataCenter = dcc.getDataCenterName();
        int totalVMs = Temp_Algo_Static_Var.vmCountMap.get(dataCenter);
        AlgoHelper ah = (AlgoHelper)Temp_Algo_Static_Var.map.get(dataCenter);
        .
        .
        .
   }
}
```

But as this method is run,name oft the 2 threads are printed.

```
Thread-11
Thread-13
```

and it is after this that the long pause occurs. Why is that ? How could the two threads enter the synchronized block,when the first thread has yet not left the block ?

Comment: Are you sure you are invoking `getNextAvailableVm()` on the same object?

Comment: are you sure your sleep is not interrupted ? (print something in the exception block)

Comment: @njzk2 nothing gets printed from the exception block

Comment: @SuhailGupta : probably because there is no print statement ?

Comment: @rocketboy comment is probably your problem. There is no reason this block should be accessed by more than one thread if properly synchronized on the same object

Comment: Try `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + this);` to check @rocketboy's suggestion.

Comment: Is my given example correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the two threads are running against the same object then this should not happen.

I would therefore suggest that **you are creating a new object for each thread** or at least some of the threads are running on different objects.

If you do want multiple objects then you should **not** use `synchronized(this)`, you should create a `static final Object` to `synchronize` on. Please do not sync on `this.getClass()` as that breaks.

Comment: How does synchronizing on this.getClass() break? And is that true also for syncing on ClassName.class?

Comment: @JensSchauder - If you synchronize on `this.getClass` then **all** objects of this type will block when **any** of them synchronize. Also a sub-class of your object will then not correctly synchronize with objects of the super class. This is almost certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are invoking `getNextAvailableVm()` on different instances of the containing class. Since you are synchronizing on `this` you will be locking on two different monitors (first thread locks on instance1, second one on instance2).

There are a lot of ways you could correct this:

- make the whole method `synchronized`
- synchronize on `this.getClass()`
- define a static object to lock on
- use methods from java.util.concurrent.locks to do the locking

These are just some suggestions to address your problem, but to find the right one we would have to know more about your application structure and your requirements.

Comment: Do not synchronize on `getClass()`. That will break if you start including subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below prog, will work like you expected,

Locked on Thread1.Class, Two thread will not execute the method simultaneously

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
        Thread1 t2 = new Thread1();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}

class Thread1 extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        getNextAvailableVm();
    }
    public void getNextAvailableVm() {
        synchronized(Thread1.class) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(Exception exc){}
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    }
}
```

OUTPUT
Thread-1
Thread-1
Thread-0
Thread-0